# WooCommerce Multiple Paypal Button On Page

Tags: wordpress, button, woocommerce, paypal

I am currently using the current PayPal plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-paypal-payments/

I would like to get multiple 'buy it now' under different  products on one page.

As seen in the screenshot below, I have added the short-code for each product ([product_page id="2546"] for example). The first PayPal button shows up fine, but any after do not.

[paypal-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXbwI.png)

Is there some sort of way of overriding this or another solution to this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is technically possible to make multiple independent PayPal buttons show on the same page (by giving them unique container ids to render each button in), but WooCommerce's plugin is not designed to work or be used this way.

Showing a PayPal button alongside a product is only intended to be used with ***1 product per page***. If multiple products are to be shown on a page, the expectation is to not have a PayPal button next to them and instead have buyer make use of the Add to Cart functionality followed by a PayPal button on the view cart page.